# ImageTag exists in the TR?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

EDIT:

```cs
public bool getImage()
{
    IWebElement table = driver.FindElement(By.Id("DIV_ID_1"));

    string name = String.Format("//*[contains(text(), \'{0}\')]", 'TEST1');
    IWebElement element = table.FindElement(By.XPath(name));
    IWebElement parent = element.FindElement(By.XPath(".."));

    try
    {
        IWebElement image = element.FindElement(By.XPath("//img"));
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

How would I find out if the `TEST1` does have `Image`? in the below html source code, I have tr and within tr i have td and some tr may have image tag and some may not

So, I will be passing name for an example: `TEST1` and in returns I will be expecting if the name has Image tag or not.

again, if I pass `TEST2` and `TEST3` it should `return` `null` since it does not have an image tag and where as `TEST1` and `TEST4` does have `Image tag` hence it should return me true.

I tried something like this but did not work:

```cs
string name = String.Format(".//td[contains(., \'{0}\')]/..//@src", "TEST1");
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(name));
```

get this error: after trying the above code...

> The xpath expression './/td[contains(., 'TEST1')]/..//@src' 
>   cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement

Below is the html source code

```html
<div id="DIV_ID_1">
    <table id="TBLID1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                TEST1
            </td>
            <td>
                <img id="ctl00" src="../App_Themes/Default/images/phone.gif" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                TEST2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                TEST3
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                TEST4
            </td>
            <td>
                <img id="ctl02" src="../App_Themes/Default/images/phone.gif" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Try removing the `string name = String.Format("//*[contains(text(), \'{0}\')]", 'TEST1');` instead just try `IWebElement element = table.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), 'TEST1')]"));` as this is not needed. And your problem is this `IWebElement image = element.FindElement(By.XPath("//img"));` it needs to be `IWebElement image = parent.FindElement(By.XPath("//img"));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I would break this up into a few steps.

First get your element:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'TEST1')]"));
```

Then get the parent element:

```
WebElement parent = element.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
```

Then check the parent element for an `<img>` tag:

```
Try
{
    WebElement image = parent.findElement(By.xpath("//img"));
}
catch (NoSuchElementException e)
{
    System.out.println("Did not find an image");
}
```

I'd wrap this in a function that I could then pass in the text to find the image and return the element if it exists.

Something like:

```
public WebElement getImage(String innerText)
```

then just pass in TEST1 or TEST2

Comment: +1'ed this since it's actually a better way to do it. The only thing I would say is that be specific in the XPath, don't use `*`, but use `td`.

Comment: i am getting the wrong image src so its extracting an image from the page and i have tested like this: `image.getattribute("src")`

Comment: so i get total of 126 count when i do `parent.FindElements(By.XPath("//img"))`

Comment: do you have more than 1 'TEST1' string on your page? And could I see the code your using?

Comment: I just tried `//td[contains(text(), 'TEST1')]/../td/img` which is what your doing and I'm only finding 1 element. I'd need to see the method you have set up.

Answer (score 0):

Using your original XPath, it works fine, executed both in Firefox and Chrome's developer tools and it returns the img. Does it actually return anything or just doesn't return what you'd expect? Does it error saying the element cannot be found?

This is another way of getting it:

```
//td[normalize-space(text())='TEST1']/../descendant::img/@src
```

Comment: Is it in an iFrame? What browser?

Comment: `The xpath expression '//td[normalize-space(text())='TEST1']/../descendant::img/@src' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement`

Comment: What happens if you try it in Chrome?

Comment: i can't due to company policy.