# How do I count xpath using 2 elements?

Tags: xpath, selenium, phpunit

I want to count the number of stars if an entry is successfully submitted. There can also be stars for entries that aren't submitted yet. If the entries aren't submitted yet, I want to ignore those entries even though there are stars for those entries that aren't submitted yet.

This is the code I want to count:

```
<table>
  <tr id="entry_row_25494">
    <td>
      <img id="star_span_25494" img="" <="" src="/images/yes_star.png" onclick="toggleStar(25494);">
    </td>
    <td>
    <img title="Entry successfully submitted" alt="Entry successfully submitted" src="/images/greencirclecheck.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="entry_row_25496">
    <td>
      <img id="star_span_25496" img="" <="" src="/images/yes_star.png" onclick="toggleStar(25496);">
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is what I have:

```
$numOfStars = $this->getXpathCount("xpath=(//img[contains(@src, 'yes_star') and (contains(@src, 'greencirclecheck.png'))])")
```

These are what I've tried so far in Selenium IDE using storeXpathCount

```
//table//img[@src='/images/yes_star.png' and @src='/images/greencirclecheck.png']
//table/tbody/tr[*]/td[*]/img[contains(@src, 'yes_star.png')]/parent::*[contains(@src, 'greencirclecheck.png')]
//img[contains(@src, 'greencirclecheck.png')]/preceding::img[contains(@src, 'yes_star.png')]
xpath=(//img[contains(@src, 'yes_star.png')]//img[contains(@src, 'greencirclecheck.png')])
```

But those doesn't work

Let me know if you need me to clarify instead of downvoting. I'm new to Selenium and PHPUnit, so the question might not be clear.

Comment: Are you saying that when an entry is submitted it generates:

<td>
  <img title="Entry successfully submitted" alt="Entry successfully submitted" src="/images/greencirclecheck.png">
</td>

Comment: Yes, sorry I left that out, and when the entry is not successfully submitted, it's blank <td></td>

Comment: Check out my response on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842182/imagetag-exists-in-the-tr/12843812#12843812 as this is almost identical. Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: @Falkenfighter I tried your response, but I couldn't get it to work. I tried it different ways.

Comment: Does each table only have 2 columns like in your example? If so you would want to find the xpath of your first <img> tag 
`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src, 'yes_star')"));` then you can navigate up two elements 
`element = element.findElement(By.xpath(".."));` do this twice to get to your <table>
then check to see if your second image is present `element.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src, 'greencirclecheck.png')"));`

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do this using PHPUnit. I'm kind of new to Selenium and PHPUnit

Comment: I edited the code. The first table row has both the elements, greencirclecheck, and star. The second table row has a star and doesn't have a greencirclecheck.

I just want to count one only since the second one doesn't have the greencirclecheck

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. Thanks for your help @Falkenfighter. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

```
$counted = 0;
    $countEntries = $this->getXpathCount("//img[contains(@id, 'star_span')]");
    for($num = 1; $num <= $countEntries; $num ++) {
        $entry = $this->getAttribute("//tr[contains(@id, 'entry_row')][".$num."]@id");
        $newEntry = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/i", "", $entry);
        if($this->isElementPresent("//tr[@id='entry_row_".$newEntry."']//img[contains(@src, 'yes_star.png')]") && $this->isElementPresent("//tr[@id='entry_row_".$newEntry."']//input[contains(@checked, 'checked')]") == true) {
            $counted ++;
        }
    }
```